# Obtain and store adjacent values from a .csv file (Python)

Tags: python, csv

It's probably easier if I explain with the .csv in question:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iswvm4xyjnlhj2w/speciesandbss.csv

The above is a list of species of Bivalves and their corresponding values for bed shear stress at their collection location from the end-Cretaceous.

I'm trying to create an occurrence plot, and I need to format my data so that the species names are in one column, with the corresponding lowest and highest value of bed shear stress (in the data set, there are multiple occurrences of the same species) alongside.

Obviously this would be very tedious to do by hand.

How can I create a loop to append each occurrence into separate lists, the name being that of the species for which the bed shear stress corresponds to? Then I can loop through each list to find the highest and lowest.

i.e.

input:

```
eggs 0.1
ham 0.2
ham 0.5
eggs 0.7
eggs 0.3
```

output:

```
eggs = [0.1, 0.7, 0.3]
ham = [0.2, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the values into a dictionary of lists; a `collections.defaultdict()` object is easiest:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

species = defaultdict(list)

with open('speciesandbss.csv', 'rb') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        species[row[0]].append(row[1])

for name in sorted(species, key=str.lower):
    print '{} = {}'.format(name, species[name])
```

Outputs:

```
acutata = ['0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509']
acutocostata = ['0.03145', '0.01936', '0.01781', '0.01698', '0.01684', '0.01077']
adkinsi = ['0.16509']
Aenona = ['0.01311', '0.01311']
aequilateralis = ['0.00495', '0.00445', '0.00368', '0.00356']
agdjakendensis = ['0.00628']
Agerostrea = ['0.01764']
albertensis = ['0.00852', '0.00356', '0.00495', '0.00461', '0.00445', '0.0041']
alta = ['0.00328', '0.33148', '0.33148', '0.43129', '0.33148', '0.325', '0.17882', '0.00307']
alternata = ['0.04929', '0.03373', '0.01311']
americana = ['0.01497', '0.00436', '0.01497', '0.00495', '0.00461', '0.00445', '0.00105']
anacachoensis = ['0.05696', '0.05696', '0.05172', '0.03373']
angulatum = ['0.01179']
anomala = ['0.00852']
Anomia = ['0.00852', '0.00506', '0.02955', '0.00786']
anteradiata = ['0.43129', '0.16509']
antroea = ['0.01373']
antrosa = ['0.01103']
Aphrodina = ['0.43129', '0.01311']
apressus = ['0.01564']
Arca = ['0.01179', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01224', '0.01224']
archeri = ['0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509']
Arctica = ['0.00203']
argentaria = ['0.01233', '0.33148', '0.33148', '0.33148', '0.33148', '0.43129', '0.43129', '0.21502', '0.01311', '0.01224', '0.00352', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01179', '0.01373', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01224', '0.01224', '0.01224', '0.01224', '0.16509', '0.01564']
armatum = ['0.33148', '0.33148', '0.33148', '0.33148']
Ascaulocardium = ['0.43129', '0.21502']
assiniboiensis = ['0.00401', '0.00436', '0.00436', '0.00685', '0.00495', '0.00495', '0.00486', '0.00461', '0.00453', '0.00445']
assiniboinensis = ['0.00117']
Astarte = ['0.01497', '0.01311']
balchii = ['0.00786']
balticus = ['0.05696', '0.05696', '0.05696', '0.05238', '0.03623', '0.03373', '0.00724', '0.04574']
barabini = ['0.01233', '0.00852', '0.00506']
Barbatia = ['0.05696', '0.03373', '0.18121', '0.17882', '0.01224']
bartoni = ['0.16509']
bartrami = ['0.325', '0.26095', '0.25697', '0.17882', '0.01311']
bella = ['0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01764']
bellisculptus = ['0.05696', '0.05696', '0.03373', '0.25697', '0.01311', '0.01224', '0.01311', '0.01224', '0.01179', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311', '0.01311']
berryi = ['0.43129', '0.17882']
biplicata = ['0.05696', '0.03373', '0.33148', '0.33148', '0.43129', '0.01224', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509']
bisulcata = ['0.01311', '0.01224', '0.01224']
borealis = ['0.01233', '0.00852', '0.00452', '0.00401', '0.00852', '0.00452', '0.00401', '0.00436', '0.01497', '0.02971']
bowiei = ['0.16509', '0.16509']
Breviarca = ['0.01311', '0.01311']
Brevicardium = ['0.16509']
brevifrons = ['0.43129']
bryani = ['0.16509']
bulbosa = ['0.16509', '0.16509', '0.16509']
burlingtonensis = ['0.05696', '0.05696', '0.04929', '0.03373', '0.325', '0.01311', '0.01179', '0.04574']
```

etc.

Writing lowest and highest values:

```
with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    writer.writerows([n, min(values), max(values)] for n, v in species.iteritems() for values in (map(float, v),))
```

Comment: would they all collect under the same keyword?

Comment: @EJMC: They all collect under the name used in the first column.

Comment: It seems to be a bit of a jump, but how would I format this to then output a .csv with: species name in column 1, lowest value in list in column 2, highest value in list in column 3?

Comment: @EJMC: Use a `csv.writer` and `writer.writerow([name, min(species[name]), max(species[name]))` of course. :-)

Comment: @EJMC: Added a 3-line version of that.

Comment: could you explain this line "species[row[0]].append(row[1])"? What happens when the programme hits it?

Comment: @EJMC: `species[row[0]]` looks up the value for a given key in the dictionary. Because the `species` object is a `defaultdict`, if that key is *not* present, the `list` factory is used to create one anyway; that means that `species[row[0]]` **always** returns a list object. The code then uses `.append(row[1])` to add the stress value to that list.

Comment: @EJMC: I discovered a slight problem with the highest - lowest code; you need to first convert the values to floats before picking the max and min values; otherwise you get values in lexographically sorted order instead (where `'10'` is sorted before `'9'` and thus is 'lower' as far as `min()` and `max()` are concerned).